# Remove item from Div Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML code and i need to remove the item from div.

### HTML

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="popcart">
<div class="media" id="2">
<a href="shop-single.html">
<span class="qty">1</span> x <span class="price">1790.00</span><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="btnpopitemclose(2)">
<div class="media" id="5">
<a href="shop-single.html">
<span class="qty">1</span> x <span class="price">1990.00</span><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="btnpopitemclose(5)">
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried it like below Jquery code.But it's not success

```
   function btnpopitemclose(ItemId) {

    $(this).closest('<div>').remove();//not success
$(this).parent('<div>').remove();//not success
$(this).remove();//not success
}
```

Comment: which item do you want to remove??

Comment: @Sushil selected item (ItemId)

Comment: you want to remove whole of `<div class="media"` this on dropdown change??

Comment: Use jQuery Selector not HTML: `"div"` not `"<div>"` for .closest().

Comment: Your HTML is malformed with no closing `</div>` on the first `class="media"`

Comment: Just curious, why do you use an id as in `id="2"`? (it has nothing to do with the actual question, just my curiosity)

Answer (score 2):

Use a jQuery Selector:

> A string containing a selector expression to match elements against.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  $("button.close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var trg = $(this).closest("div");
    console.log("Removing " + trg.attr("id"));
    trg.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="popcart">
  <div class="media" id="2">
    <a href="shop-single.html">
      <span class="qty">1</span> x <span class="price">1790.00</span>
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"> x </button>
  </div>
  <div class="media" id="5">
    <a href="shop-single.html">
      <span class="qty">1</span> x <span class="price">1990.00</span>
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"> x </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It may be better to attach the event handler to the grandparent element `$("#popcart").on('click','button.close',function(e) {` making the removal cleaner internally i.e. also `var trg = $(this).closest("div.media");` should be less fragile

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you may be right. I was shooting for more portable script.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is work for your dropdown change event

If it's a button click then replace `$('#popcart').off().on('change',` by `$('#popcart').off().on('click',` i.e `click` event

```
$('#popcart').off().on('change',function(){
var $this=$(this);
$this.closest('div[class="media"]').remove();
});
```

Comment: Please explain WHY you did the off/on and change here here `.off().on('change'` as that seems odd, and why `'div[class="media"]'` when `'div.media'` is cleaner for jQuery?  Is there a reason you create a variable here? `var $this=$(this);` since it is a simple single on the `.remove()`?

Answer (score 0):

give id to parent attribute of the attribute that you want to remove here i have used id "main_div" i am removing 2nd child of parent div

you can write 
$("#main_div").child().next().remove();

hope it works for you

Comment: This makes no sense since it already has an id `id="popcart"`, although this may account for the malformed markup which appears to just be a typo perhaps.  I commented on the question regarding that malformation.